# zxing finderpatternfinder in java

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I 'm trying like Barcode Scanner App in Android Create Java Code Can Mark Finder Pattern in QRCode Image By Zxing Library, But I Can't get to it. Can anyone help me ?
Something like this [photo Link](http://eric-yuan.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/finderp.jpg)

My Coding Attempt

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.ChecksumException;
import com.google.zxing.FormatException;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Reader;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder;

public class Zxing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                "F:\\Desktop-1394-01-23\\Form\\Form-Data.jpg");
        BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        try {
            FinderPatternFinder Fpf = new FinderPatternFinder(
                    bitmap.getBlackMatrix());
            System.out.println(Fpf);
        } catch (NotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println(bitmap);
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        try {
            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
            System.out.println("Barcode text is " + result.getText());
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ChecksumException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your coding attempt. Refer to [this guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) while posting questions.

Comment: I Use finderpatternfinder in package qr.detector but this class not return anything